# XNA 4.0 Security Camera Feature

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm looking to make a security camera type feature in a game I want to design. The idea that I have is that there will be a designated rectangle similar to a TV screen in the game and I want to be able to display in that rectangle area what a Camera sees in a specific room.

So to setup a specific scenario, let's say we have Room A and Room B. I want in Room B to be a TV Screen that displays what is currently shown in Room A. I know this must be possible some how using the XNA camera functions, I'm just really unsure how I would output what the camera sees in that area and then show it in the designated sprite rectangle in Room B.

Hopefully this makes sense or is possible :D

TKs,
Shane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to render your security camera scene to a custom `RenderTarget2D`, which you can then use as though it were a `Texture2D`.

The 5 basic steps to this are:

- Create a custom `RenderTarget2D`
- Tell your `GraphicsDevice` to render to this new target
- Render your 'screen' scene
- Reset the render target
- Texture your screen polygon with the texture created by the render target

For more information, see [Riemer's XNA tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php).

Comment: Wow this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks for the awesome response kendall :D